# Let $n$ be an even perfect number and $p > n$ be prime. Then $\sigma_{p-2}(n) \equiv 2 \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

By Euclid-Euler theorem, $n = 2^{q-1}(2^{q} - 1)$ where $2^{q} - 1$ is prime. Since $\sigma_{p-2}(n)$ is multiplicative and $(2^{q-1},2^{q} - 1) = 1$,

$$
\begin{align}
\sigma_{p-2}(n) &= \sigma_{p-2}(2^{q-1})\sigma_{p-2}(2^{q} - 1)\\ &= (1^{p-2} + 2^{p-2} + \cdot\cdot\cdot +2^{(q-1)(p-2)})(1^{p-2} + (2^{q} - 1)^{p-2})\\ &= (1 + 2^{p-2} + \cdot\cdot\cdot +2^{(q-1)(p-2)})(1 + (2^{q} - 1)^{p-2}).
\end{align}
$$

From the looks of it I can't find a way to subtract $2$ from the expression then subsequently factor out $p$ (that way we reach the desired conclusion). Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You only need $d^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p$. Then $$n\sum_{d|n}d^{p-2} \equiv \sum_{d| n}n/d \equiv \sum_{d|n}d \equiv 2n\bmod p$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate briefly on how you came up with this (i.e. the theorems you applied) (i'll try to fill in the gaps) thanks!

Comment: "you only need..."

Comment: What i meant was how did you come up with the arithmetic functions and the congruences

Comment: I don't see what you mean. $\sum_{d|n} d^{p-2}$ is the definition of $\sigma_{p-2}(n)$.

Comment: What I don't understand is how come $n\sum_{d \mid n} d^{p-2} \equiv \sum_{d \mid n} \frac{n}{d} \equiv \sum_{d \mid n} d \equiv 2n \pmod p$

Comment: $d^{p-1}\equiv 1$ so $nd^{p-2}\equiv n/d$. The middle step is obvious. The last step is using that $n$ is perfect.

Comment: I now get all the steps but the middle one. Why is $\frac{n}{d} \equiv d \pmod p?$

Comment: $\sum_{d|n} d=\sum_{d|n} n/d$ try with $n=12$

Comment: but 12 is not a perfect number? is there a more rigorous way of arriving to this?

Comment: Come on it is completely obvious that $\sum_{d|n} d=\sum_{d|n} n/d$ for all $n$